# Listing active NDIS filters

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, packet-capture, ndis

I am performing a multilayer packet capture on Windows using the built-in NDIS capture service in order to determine where in the stack packets for my application are being dropped. When viewing the resulting ETL file in Microsoft Message Analyzer, I'm provided with data points containing two items in particular that I'm looking for:

1. MiniportIfIndex - this corresponds with the adapter interface ID, which I can translate into a logical name by running Get-NetAdapter in PowerShell (as one method).
2. LowerIfIndex - this is the specific layer/filter of the NDIS stack that the packet is progressing through during the traffic flow and is the subject of this question.

I have yet to find a way to gather what specific layer/filter the lowerIfIndex is referencing. I found [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ndis/2011/04/06/exploring-ndiss-wmi-classes/) which led me to the WMI class `MSNdis_EnumerateReceiveFilters` that I was hoping would give me an output similar to that of Get-NetAdapter, listing the logical name of the filter as well as the corresponding ID. When I try to run the command in the format similar to how the MSDN article references, I'm always receiving an 'incorrect parameter' stop error.

One other command `Get-NetAdapterBinding` appears to display the logical names of the NDIS filters/layers, but no corresponding ID.

Is anyone aware of a way to correlate the lowerIfIndex to a filter name?

Comment: When using the wmi cmdlets, the `MSNdis_EnumerateReceiveFilters` class doesn't have any methods besides `WmiEnumReceiveFilters` which takes a `MSNdis_WmiMethodHeader` argument

Comment: It looks like this method actually wants two arguments: the `MSNdis_WmiMethodHeader` and a `MSNdis_ReceiveFilterInfoArray`. Running a `Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class MSNdis_ReceiveFilterInfoArray` returns nothing. Supplying a $null value in the place where the argument should be for the WmiEnumReceiveFilters method doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: On my W7, PSv5 box, it only shows one argument in the definition.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. For reference, I am running this on either Windows Server 2012 R2 with PS v5 or Windows 10 v1607 with PS v5.1.